# Core Motion in the background?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-motion

Will Core Motion framework work while the app is in the background?

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfying answer?

Comment: I already saw some pedometers getting the data of core motion after returning from background mode. so there should be a way to keep receiving data via `startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue`. For me it works a few seconds/minutes after i put the app to background but after some time it stops. maybe you have to use one of the background modes (audio, location, voip) to keep the app "alive".

Answer (score 1):

The Core Motion framework allows access to historical data for CMPedometer data, so if your app is only using this there is no need to run in the background.

I have been playing around with CM the last week and in my testing if you have an active query running when your app is sent to the background, the query handler receives a flood of events (that occurred while the app was suspended) upon returning to the foreground. I don't know how many events will be cached, and I haven't seen anything in the docs about this.

This behaviour seems to be sufficient. I can't think of a use case for Core Motion where you need constant background access, historical CMPedometer data doesn't suffice, and fits within the App Store guidelines.

Comment: You are right on everything, but there's a use case for CMPedometer when the app is in background: if you show the number of steps in the badge on the app icon, then you need to wake up your app every once in a while (when iOS background mode decides it's fit) and update its badge count; since you can't have access to the live stream while in background, you can work around it with `queryPedometerData(from start: Date, to end: Date, withHandler handler: @escaping CMPedometerHandler)`.

Comment: I guess Apple lets that one through since it's uncommon and mostly harmless.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your definition of working... Will Core Animation need to continue running or are you expecting the view to be frozen?  When an app runs in the background only certain processes are allowed to run.  (Notifications for example).

For the most part the application UI, and by extension is paused until you trigger *applicationDidBecomeActive*.  Once that starts up again it should resume, but again not continue running in the background.  Same can be said for most games on iOS running OpenGL, it's paused until the app is active again.

Answer (score 0):

one of the apps- moves that is used to track your walking steps  is quite amazing, because even you make it into background or killed, it can indicate the steps you walked. So some internal mechanism of gyroscope and GPS and other sensors can carry on when the apps are killed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to let your app run in the background, you have to declare it as a background task. The problem is that there are only a few [UIBackgroundModes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) ... and motion isn't one of it.

A workaround could be to enable the UIBackgroundMode `location`, which is intended to let users know about their location even if the app is in the background. You could then wrap your motion logic within. Nevertheless, the clear drawback of this is that it involves usage of the GPS, which will drain the battery significantly...

Comment: If enable background mode of location, please remember to add this statement to the app description on app store **"Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically decrease battery life."** Otherwise, app store review won't approve the app.

Comment: If your app is not clearly using the Core Location framework in the background, you'll have slim chances of being accepted.